# Is it fine to run a public website on the sql express db?

Tags: sql-server-2008, express-edition

Is it fine to run a public high traffic website on a sql server 2008 express db?
[image]

Comment: You need to define "high traffic."

Comment: I mean something with traffic as this website but the website will access the db from each user browser every few second to get updated data.

Comment: You can run a public website off SQL Express with great performance. You can run a public website off a DataCenter edition with fusionio SSDs and terrabytes of RAM and the site can perform like crap. As long as the database has a sound design, the engine and response time should be fine. It might make sense to do some caching in your app, maybe not but just because it's free, doesn't mean it's dreck. It's your design and your access methodology that will make all the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a partial list of restrictions of this version:

- Number of CPUs:  1
- Maximum memory utilized:  1 GB
- Maximum database size:  10 GB
- Replication: Subscriber only
- Backup compression: N/A
- Most of performance features is not available.
- ...

See [comparison list](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of high traffic, it is likely that you will see awful performance. If there is any transactional writes that happen often, you'll cap out the max database size rather quickly, and as mentioned above there are many hardware restrictions on express. Not to mention you don't have all the creature comforts for a professional enterprise instance (SQL Agent, etc.).

SQL Server express is more for embedded applications, or very small low-budget intranet applications.